# bind gridview without doing postback without using update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gridview binding data from database without doing postback on the select of item in dropdown.

i know it is possible through ajax update panel but for some specific reason it can't use it.

And i think that gridview is a server-side control and if i implement it by using table structure , jquery ajax and web service  then it will loose all gridview properties of edit, update and paging etc.

So please help on this matter.

googling from 2-3 days but unable to find the solution,

a little help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without post-back because drop-down is server control it fires on post-back only according your need it is not possible

Comment: postback isn't a issue, web service and jquery ajax will sort out it much better.

main issue is to bind grid data without doing postback with full gridview functionality.

thanks anyway for your reply

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Because the data for grid in database. Without server side scripting you cant the access Database.

Or Better u go for to write WCF service From the result set of WCF Service you can organize 
grid table with javascript.

But you cant achieve full functionality of grid view with this one.And It take Lots of time also.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes i think it will take a lot of time and logic to create such functional gridtable structure.

Thanks for reply